# get_block returns empty tx_hashes array

Tags: monerod, rpc

I am trying to use the get_block JSON RPC endpoint documented here: https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_block

The trouble I'm having is that when I call it, the returned data structure has an empty array at `result.json.tx_hashes`. The documentation suggests that the `tx_hashes` field should have an array of all the tx hashes included in the block. But whatever block I search for, the array is empty. I've tried this with multiple independent nodes (my own plus a couple of public ones).

To take an example from the block explorer, if I query the `get_transactions` endpoint for TXID `88169753514b6732bb28cf73e4dd58b9f0a2863d5851f43110ff10e6879f3254`, the returned data shows that this TX is included in the block at height 2631608. But if I call the `get_block` endpoint for height 2631608, then the tx_hashes array is empty.

Is this a known issue in the monerod RPC interface? Or am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's there and working (I verified on multiple nodes):

```
curl -sd '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"getblock","params":{"height":2631608}}' \
    http://node.supportxmr.com:18081/json_rpc | jq .result.tx_hashes
[                                                                    
   "88169753514b6732bb28cf73e4dd58b9f0a2863d5851f43110ff10e6879f3254",
   ...
   "3f8a44ad64e88c0b6e0a1c81e297a675dd28926740ef0d085b21186bc240df01"
]
```

If you don't see it, try another node.

Comment: Never mind, problem was just me being dumb. Didn't have the "height" argument in the "Params" sub-object, just had it in the main json body. Apologies.